# API метрики и js

Tags: javascript, cors

Пробую получать через js данные с api метрики, но ничего не выходит, получаю ошибку:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api-metrika.yandex.ru/stat/v1/data?id=36783295&metrics=ym:s:visits,ym:s:users
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://vh17725.hv5.ru' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Неужели с яндекса нельзя брать через js данные? или может какие то для этого способы есть все таки?

Comment: А как вы их пытаетесь загрузить?

Comment: @Jean-Claude, через библиотеку restangular

Comment: Между доменами обычно запрещен обмен данными, но вы можете зпгрузить их с помощью curl.